# Copy content of HTM file into clipboard

Tags: autohotkey

I have a textual htm file saved locally on my machine and I would like to copy the content of it into Clipboard using an `AutoHotKey` script. I tried:

```
FileRead, Clipboard, *c C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.htm
```

and

```
UrlDownloadToFile, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.htm, NewTextFile.txt
```

But neither of them worked. 
The only workaround I could think of, was to open the htm file in browser using:

```
Run, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.htm
```

and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and next <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but that's not ideal.

Comment: Why the `*c` option?

`FileRead, Clipboard, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.htm`

Should work just fine for you.

Comment: @Bob **Nope**. `Clipboard` is still BLANK. Is there something wrong my my machine? Would the above line of code work on your machine? i.e. would it send the contents of htm file into `Clipboard`?

Comment: I don't know if something is wrong with your machine. For me it does work even with big over 10 MB file. No idea why it would help but have you tried with`FileRead` saving to other variable and then using `clipboard:=var`? You can also try to `clipboard:=RegexReplace(var,"\0","+")` to replace NULL characters. Who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you absolutely sure the path is correct? If you do this:

```
FileRead, Clipboard, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.htm
MsgBox %ErrorLevel%
```

what does the MsgBox say? "ErrorLevel is set to 0 if the load was successful. It is set to 1 if a problem occurred such as: 1) file does not exist; 2) file is locked or inaccessible; 3) the system lacks sufficient memory to load the file." Source: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm

Which version of AutoHotkey do you have installed? If you have a very old version it may have difficulties reading a Unicode (utf-8) file (not sure).
Be sure to download and install the most recent version if possible https://autohotkey.com/download/

FileRead should just work. But it will read the contents of the HTML code to the clipboard. If you want the formatted text of the HTML file, so paragraphs, bold, italics, lists, tables etc. You need a different technique using the WinClip() library.

1. Download and unpack the WinClip() library from here https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/74670-class-winclip-direct-clipboard-manipulations/
2. Create a new script, this will read the HTML file and read the formatted text into memory and paste it (do this in for example Office or other programs that accept formatted input):

   ```
   #Include WinClipAPI.ahk
   #Include WinClip.ahk
   wc := new WinClip

   WinClip.Clear()

   FileRead, html, C:\Users\%A_UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\file.htm
   WinClip.SetHTML(html)
   WinClip.Paste()
   ```

Source: [How to send formatted/rich data (formatted text, links, images, etc) - #4](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=8977)

*Note: I use the same technique in my own [Lintalist](http://lintalist.github.io/) program.*

Comment: Thanks @lintalist. Unfortunately this thread is deceased by now as I no longer work in the office which I needed this code for. Therefore I have no mean to test your suggestions. But once again, I truly appreciate your time and effort.